# WinMain Parameter -> Mailslot -> File -> Encoding?

Tags: c++, winapi, winmain, mailslot

I've got the following problem:
An application calls every second a C++ program with some parameters to extract data from this application. The C++ programm is a `WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, PSTR szCmdLine, int iCmdShow)` to accomplish that the console-window is not shown to the user.
This "first program" checks data and then writes it into an Mailslot, hosted by my "second program" (just a normal `int main()` C++).
This already works like written above, BUT when I try to read the contents of the mailslot the encoding seems to be different because my parameters are not readable and the length of the string is different.

both programs are using Unicode in their properties. I tried both using `LPWSTR` (for Unicode) and `LPCSTR` (for ANSI) and the corresponding functions `...W` and `...A` but I didn't get it working.
below i've written my "LPCSTR-Version" of my 2 programs.

My first program looks like this:

```
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR szCmdLine, int iCmdShow)
{
    // here I do: string test = szCmdLine;
    // the parameters are like: "k1234.1234 4321.321 0 1"
    // so there is no special character, just two double and to int
    // asking for minimum length and number of spaces in it to get number of parameters
    // if there is anything not ok I return "",
    // if there is all ok, I return szCmdLine.
    LPCSTR message = processParameter((LPCSTR)szCmdLine);

    if (strcmp('', message) == 0)
        return 0;

    HANDLE hSlot;

    hSlot = CreateFile(
        L"\\\\.\\mailslot\\name\\of\\the\\slot",
        GENERIC_WRITE,              // DesiredAccess
        FILE_SHARE_READ,            // ShareMode
        (LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES)NULL,// SecurityAttributes
        OPEN_EXISTING,              // CreationDisposition
        FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,      // FlagsAndAttributes
        (HANDLE)NULL                // TemplateFile
        );

    if (hSlot == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        return 0;

    // send message
    BOOL fResult;
    DWORD cbWritten;

    fResult = WriteFile(
        hSlot,
        message,
        (DWORD)(lstrlenA(message) + 1)*sizeof(char),
        &cbWritten,
        (LPOVERLAPPED)NULL
        );  

    // Handle Clean-up
    CloseHandle(hFile);

    return 0;
}
```

In my second program looks like this:

```
HANDLE hMailSlot    = NULL;

BOOL WINAPI createMailSlot()
{
    hMailSlot = CreateMailslot(
        L"\\\\.\\mailslot\\name\\of\\the\\slot",
        0,                          // no maximum message size 
        MAILSLOT_WAIT_FOREVER,      // no time-out for operations 
        (LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES)NULL // default security
        );

    if (hMailSlot == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        printf("CreateMailslot failed with error %d\n", GetLastError());
        return FALSE;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Mailslot created successfully.\n");
    }

    return TRUE;
}

void processMessage(LPCSTR msg)
{
    string message = msg;

    // DEBUGGING
    cout << "Message: " << message << endl;
    cout << "length:  " << message.length() << endl;

    // do other things...
}

BOOL readSlot()
{
    DWORD cbMessage;
    DWORD cMessage;
    DWORD cbRead;
    BOOL fResult;
    LPCSTR lpszBuffer;
    CHAR achID[80];
    DWORD cAllMessages;
    HANDLE hEvent;
    OVERLAPPED ov;

    cbMessage = cMessage = cbRead = 0;

    hEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, FALSE, FALSE, TEXT("ExampleSlot"));
    if (NULL == hEvent)
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
    ov.Offset = 0;
    ov.OffsetHigh = 0;
    ov.hEvent = hEvent;

    fResult = GetMailslotInfo(
        hMailSlot,      // mailslot handle 
        (LPDWORD)NULL,  // no maximum message size 
        &cbMessage,     // size of next message 
        &cMessage,      // number of messages 
        (LPDWORD)NULL   // no read time-out
        );
    if (!fResult)
    {
        printf("GetMailslotInfo failed with %d.\n", GetLastError());
        CloseHandle(hEvent);
        return FALSE;
    }

    if (cbMessage == MAILSLOT_NO_MESSAGE)
    {
        printf("Waiting for a message...\n");
        CloseHandle(hEvent);
        return TRUE;
    }

    cAllMessages = cMessage;

    while (cMessage != 0)  // retrieve all messages
    {
        // Create a message-number string. 
        StringCchPrintfA(
            achID,
            80,
            "",
            cAllMessages - cMessage + 1,
            cAllMessages);

        // Allocate memory for the message.
        lpszBuffer = (LPCSTR)GlobalAlloc(
            GPTR,
            cbMessage
            );
        if (NULL == lpszBuffer)
        {
            CloseHandle(hEvent);
            return FALSE;
        }

        fResult = ReadFile(
            hMailSlot,
            (LPVOID)lpszBuffer,
            cbMessage,
            &cbRead,
            &ov
            );

        if (!fResult)
        {
            printf("ReadFile failed with %d.\n", GetLastError());
            GlobalFree((HGLOBAL)lpszBuffer);
            CloseHandle(hEvent);
            return FALSE;
        }

        // process Message
        processMessage(lpszBuffer);

        // Concatenate the message and the message-number string. 

        StringCbCatA(
            (STRSAFE_LPSTR)lpszBuffer,
            cbMessage,
            achID
            );

        GlobalFree((HGLOBAL)lpszBuffer);

        fResult = GetMailslotInfo(
            hMailSlot,      // mailslot handle 
            (LPDWORD)NULL,  // no maximum message size 
            &cbMessage,     // size of next message 
            &cMessage,      // number of messages 
            (LPDWORD)NULL   // no read time-out
            );

        if (!fResult)
        {
            printf("GetMailslotInfo failed (%d)\n", GetLastError());
            CloseHandle(hEvent);
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
    CloseHandle(hEvent);
    return TRUE;
}

int main()
{
    if(!createMailSlot())
        return 1;

    while (true)
    {
        // check Mailslot for messages
        readSlot();

        Sleep(1000);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

`processMessage()` gives then a different parameter-string than submitted to my first program. It looks quite weird and is not readable...

Is there a solution for my problem? Where are my faults?

**EDIT:** I edited my whole question including the source code, to show my latest version.

Comment: For one, stop using C-style casts, those only help you hide and ignore errors until runtime. Then, you don't have a defined file format (or mailslot format) if you use TCHAR in the writing, because this type depends on the compile settings. If you used the same string type consistently on both sides, you wouldn't have encoding issues.

Comment: Avoid using `TCHAR` use either ANSI or UNICODE and the corresponding `...A` and `...W` versions of the Windows API (unless you need to build an application that is available for both ANSI and UNICODE).  Especially if you are reading from another application.

Comment: thank you both, Ulrich Eckhardt and Richard Critten for you comments. I'll try to change my programs like you suggested and will write back here, when i've got results!

Comment: You prevent the system from creating a console by specifying an appropriate [/SUBSYSTEM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fcc1zstk.aspx) to the linker. Relying on the linker to pick a /SUBSYSTEM based on a particular function signature is not recommended.

Comment: You don't need to target the windows subsystem. Target the console subsystem but ask CreateProcess not to show the console window.

Comment: @SaschaP I will say it more emphatically - *Never cast a string type to another string type*.  If you write code where you're casting any string type to another type, your code is wrong.   Strings need to be *converted*, not *casted*, and to do the conversion, functions have to be called.  All you're doing when you merely did a C-style cast was to shut the compiler up, which is disastrous for string types when you run your program.

Comment: As for the encodings, you'll receive whatever you send. It looks like you don't know how you encoded the text before you sent it.

Comment: @SaschaP Also, if you must use `TCHAR` and `std::(w)string` together in a program, use `typedef std::basic_string<TCHAR> TCharString;` and use `TCharString` in your program in place of `std::(w)string`.

Comment: I found this code here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365794(v=vs.85).aspx. So theoretically it should use the same encoding... So at least I have to adapt WriteFile() and ReadFile() to get the message the right way. But how to do that?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt please see my above comment. I am grateful for any help

Comment: The code above still uses C-style casts (`LPTSTR msg = (LPTSTR)w_str.c_str()`) which makes it wrong. I'm not even going to look any further at that code.

Comment: @RichardCritten I found this code here: msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/…. So theoretically it should use the same encoding... So at least I have to adapt WriteFile() and ReadFile() to get the message the right way. But how to do that?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I edited my code now to remove all C-style casts. Are you willing to help me now?

Comment: There is nothing C++ in your code , it's basically C code ,  also   LPCSTR is just typdef for char* , which makes this line 
    if (message == "")
        return 0; to fail always (you're comparing pointers here, not strings)

Comment: @user3613500 if i change `if (message == "")` to `if (message == '')` my VS13 underlines the code red _the character string has to contain at least one character_ but it gets compiled. So i'll change it in my code!

Comment: it doesn't matter . the point you need to use strcmp and not == since char* is not an object with == operator overloaded!.

Comment: @user3613500 code updated

Comment: `LPCSTR` is rather `char const*` not `char*`, just check the actual definition. `(LPDWORD)NULL` and others is still there. I see that you might need some casts, e.g. for `GlobalAlloc()`, but those should probably be `static_casts`. Your code should compile without any warnings, if there are any left, add them to the question here. Other than that, check the call to `StringCbCatA()`, I'm not sure you're using it right.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I answered my question. code is now working! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally I found a solution for my problem.
I just copied again the example-code of MSDN (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365576%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and then googled around.
I found this site http://www.johndcook.com/blog/cplusplus_strings/ where all string representations are listed and explained. I changed some passages of my code and this is my working version:

first program:

```
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR szCmdLine, int iCmdShow)
{
    // get parameters
    char *parameter = szCmdLine;

    // validate parameters
    if (!test_parameter(parameter))
    {
        return 1;
    }

    // Convert char* to a wchar_t*
    size_t origsize = strlen(parameter) + 1;
    const size_t newsize = 100;
    size_t convertedChars = 0;
    wchar_t wcstring[newsize];
    mbstowcs_s(&convertedChars, wcstring, origsize, parameter, _TRUNCATE);
    // Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235631(VS.80).aspx

    HANDLE hMailSlot;

    hMailSlot = CreateFile(
        L"\\\\.\\mailslot\\name\\of\\the\\MailSlot",    // lpFileName
        GENERIC_WRITE,              // DesiredAccess
        FILE_SHARE_READ,            // ShareMode
        (LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES)NULL,// SecurityAttributes
        OPEN_EXISTING,              // CreationDisposition
        FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,      // FlagsAndAttributes
        (HANDLE)NULL                // TemplateFile
        );

    // testing mailslot
    if (hMailSlot == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        return 2;
    }

    BOOL fResult;
    DWORD cbWritten;

    // convert message to TCHAR for sending
    TCHAR *message = wcstring;

    // send message
    fResult = WriteFile(
        hMailSlot,                                      // File
        message,                                        // Buffer
        (DWORD)(lstrlen(message) + 1)*sizeof(TCHAR),    // NumberOfBytesToWrite
        &cbWritten,                                     // NumberOfBytesWritten
        (LPOVERLAPPED)NULL                              // Overlapped
        );                          

    // Handle Clean-up
    CloseHandle(hMailSlot);

    return 0;
}
```

second program:

```
HANDLE hMailSlot = NULL;

BOOL WINAPI createMailSlot()
{
    hMailSlot = CreateMailslot(
        L"\\\\.\\mailslot\\name\\of\\the\\MailSlot",            // Slot Name
        0,                          // no maximum message size 
        MAILSLOT_WAIT_FOREVER,      // no time-out for operations 
        (LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES)NULL // default security
        );

    if (hMailSlot == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        printf("CreateMailslot failed with error %d\n", GetLastError());
        return FALSE;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Mailslot created successfully.\n");
    }

    return TRUE;
}

void processMessage(LPTSTR msg)
{
    // convert LPTSTR to string
    wchar_t *message_w = msg;
    size_t max = 100;
    char *message_c = new char[wcslen(message_w)];
    size_t message_c_size = 100;
    size_t *NumOfCharConverted = 0;
    wcstombs_s(NumOfCharConverted, message_c, message_c_size, message_w, max);
    string message(message_c);

    // processs message as string...
}

BOOL readSlot()
{
    DWORD cbMessage, cMessage, cbRead;
    BOOL fResult;
    LPTSTR lpszBuffer;
    TCHAR achID[80];
    DWORD cAllMessages;
    HANDLE hEvent;
    OVERLAPPED ov;

    cbMessage = cMessage = cbRead = 0;

    hEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, FALSE, FALSE, TEXT("ExampleSlot"));
    if (NULL == hEvent)
        return FALSE;
    ov.Offset = 0;
    ov.OffsetHigh = 0;
    ov.hEvent = hEvent;

    fResult = GetMailslotInfo(
        hMailSlot,      // mailslot handle 
        (LPDWORD)NULL,  // no maximum message size 
        &cbMessage,     // size of next message 
        &cMessage,      // number of messages 
        (LPDWORD)NULL); // no read time-out 

    if (!fResult)
    {
        printf("GetMailslotInfo failed with %d.\n", GetLastError());
        return FALSE;
    }

    if (cbMessage == MAILSLOT_NO_MESSAGE)
    {
        printf("Waiting for a message...\n");
        return TRUE;
    }

    cAllMessages = cMessage;

    while (cMessage != 0)  // retrieve all messages
    {
        // Create a message-number string. 

        StringCchPrintf((LPTSTR)achID,
            80,
            TEXT(""), //TEXT("\nMessage #%d of %d\n"),
            cAllMessages - cMessage + 1,
            cAllMessages);

        // Allocate memory for the message. 

        lpszBuffer = (LPTSTR)GlobalAlloc(GPTR,
            lstrlen((LPTSTR)achID)*sizeof(TCHAR) + cbMessage);
        if (NULL == lpszBuffer)
            return FALSE;
        lpszBuffer[0] = '\0';

        fResult = ReadFile(
            hMailSlot,
            lpszBuffer,
            cbMessage,
            &cbRead,
            &ov);

        if (!fResult)
        {
            printf("ReadFile failed with %d.\n", GetLastError());
            GlobalFree((HGLOBAL)lpszBuffer);
            return FALSE;
        }


        processMessage(lpszBuffer);

        // Concatenate the message and the message-number string. 

        StringCbCat(lpszBuffer,
            lstrlen((LPTSTR)achID)*sizeof(TCHAR) + cbMessage,
            (LPTSTR)achID);

        // Display the message. 

        _tprintf(TEXT("Contents of the mailslot: %s\n"), lpszBuffer);

        GlobalFree((HGLOBAL)lpszBuffer);

        fResult = GetMailslotInfo(
            hMailSlot,      // mailslot handle 
            (LPDWORD)NULL,  // no maximum message size 
            &cbMessage,     // size of next message 
            &cMessage,      // number of messages 
            (LPDWORD)NULL); // no read time-out 

        if (!fResult)
        {
            printf("GetMailslotInfo failed (%d)\n", GetLastError());
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
    CloseHandle(hEvent);
    return TRUE;
}

int main()
{
    if(!createMailSlot())
        return 1;

    while (true)
    {
        // check Mailslot for messages
        readSlot();

        Sleep(1000);
    }
    return 0;
}
```